# Is it possible to create non-existent parent page in Craft?

Tags: entries, redirect

I'm trying to create a new parent subfolder (/dogs) with child pages (/dogs/*). The child pages will have content: [www.example.com/dogs/german-shepherd](http://www.example.com/dogs/german-shepherd), [www.example.com/dogs/chihuahua](http://www.example.com/dogs/chihuahua), [www.example.com/dogs/pitbull](http://www.example.com/dogs/pitbull). There will be NO actual parent page [www.example.com/dogs](http://www.example.com/dogs) at this time. In other words, we do not want a true "top level page" for the subfolder. How should I go about setting this up in Craft? In case it's helpful to know, we already have the children pages but they're under different URLs built off the root so would need to also move those. For example: [www.example.com/german-shepherd](http://www.example.com/german-shepherd). Thank you!

Comment: What kind of section are you using to hold the dog entries? Channel or Structure?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the parent page.

If I understand it correctly:

1. Create a section for your content named dogs. It could be a structure or channel (depends if you need it hierarchically or chronologically).
2. At Entry URI Format you just type `dogs/{slug}`

After this, every new entry of dog, will get the address `example.com/dogs/name-of-breed`

And therefore, there is no example.com/dogs-page. But you could this page to another route, if you like. If not, there will be your 404 page shown.

So `Settings -> Routes` could be helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to leverage Craft’s template routing, by creating a template `templates/dogs.twig` (or if you prefer, `templates/dogs/index.twig`).

As long as there isn’t a “real” `https://example.com/dogs`URL in your system (ie an element or a custom route), visiting that URL with such a template in place will automatically render that template.

The `dogs.twig` template itself can either be completely blank, or you use it to redirect the user someplace else, by adding a `{% redirect %}` tag to it:

```
{% redirect siteUrl %}
```

More info about routing and how Craft resolves URLs for incoming requests can be found [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html).